# VBA macro to subtract one variable number (dynamic) from a fixed number

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, subtraction

I am after a dynamic macro that subtracts numbers in C2 onwards from B2 onwards and puts them in D2 onwards.
Numbers in C2 onwards are fixed, although the user will put numbers in B2 onwards. The length of Column C (Hours Charged) changes dependent on the sheet that has been imported. The code is as follows:

```
Dim O As Long
O = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Cells(O + 1, "C").Formula = "=SUM(C2:C" & O & ")"
Cells(O + 1, "C").Interior.Color = RGB(208, 247, 197)
Cells(O + 1, "C").Font.Bold = True
```

The sheet looks something like this (the first column is B, the last is D):

```
Hours Budgeted | Hours Charged | Variance
       0       |     85        |  0
       0       |     31        |  0
       0       |     20        |  0
       0       |     100       |  0
       0       |     75        |  0
```

To summarise, when a user inputs a value in the Hours Budgeted (B) column, i want it to automatically subtract from the Hours Charged (C) column and display in the Variance (D) column.
The reason why this can't just be a '=C2-B2' is because I have a macro inputting all this data, as well as a separate macro that 'Resets' the sheet (removing all data and formulas).

Thanks all,
Jake.

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Your example doesn't look very helpful - why is everything zero?

Comment: The code displayed is just there as an FYI. The issue i'm having is displaying the subtraction result of the first two columns in the third column, once someone inputs data into the first column. Hours Budgeted will always be zero until the user inputs the data. The Variance column is where i need the formula (hence why it's 0).

Comment: if you want things to happen when a user enters data you need to investigate worksheet events, probably the change event in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do the trick, just add it after the code you posted.

```
For i = 2 To O
    Cells(i, "D").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[-2]"
Next i
```

FormulaR1C1 lets you insert cells references that are relative to the cell you're putting the formula into, so R[2]C[3] would insert a reference to a cell three rows down and three columns to the right.